# Add product to quote

Tags: magento-1.7, php, wishlist, addtocart

I have problem in wishlist

I need to move products from **wishlist** to **enquiry quote**

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('qquoteadv/index/addItem/');
$actionQuote = "addQuote('".$url."');"
```

i tried above code but its not working

any suggestion for this query?

Comment: what is this ?where you have  put code?please describe briefly?

Answer (score 1):

From the standard Magento Wishlist controller there is an action `cartAction` which will take items from a wishlist and add the item to the cart.

It takes an item id and will then add the item to the quote.

Check out the core files:

1) `Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Column_Cart` which renders the JavaScript to add the item to the cart,

2) `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/item/column/cart.phtml` this is the default template for wishlist items,

3) `Mage_Wishlist_IndexController` the controller for adding wishlist items to the cart-